# Indexing of lists within a list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of lists in python.

```
z=[[0]*6]*7
```

Since all elements are 0. But now if i want to change an individual element within a list e.g

```
z[0][0]=2
```

This should change the first element of the first list. But it actually changes the first element of all elements. This is so illogical to me.
Can some one help.

```
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a classical "programmer's trap" in python.

```
l = [ 0 ] * 6
```

creates a list containing six times a *reference* to the **same** python object, here, the numerical constant `0`.

Now, setting

```
l[0] = 1
```

will *replace* the first reference to the `const 0` object by a reference to another object, the `const 1` object.

Now, let's look at

```
z=[[0]*6]*7
```

This first creates a list containing six references to the `const 0` object, and then it creates a list containing seven references to that **single** six-element list.

Now,

```
z[0]
```

will give you the first element from `z`, which is simply the **same** as all the six other elements.

Proof:

```
print id(z[0]) == id(z[1])
```

different objects have different IDs.

So you never actually made a list of different lists, but just the same list all over.

You can actually create different sublists and put them into one by doing something like

```
z = [ [0]*6 for _ in range(7) ]
```

However, I get the feeling you actually might want to use matrices – if that's really the case, `numpy`'s `ndarray` is what you're after, because:

```
import numpy
z = numpy.ndarray((7,6))
```

actually gives you a matrix with 42 numeric elements.